# Data structure to handle the requirement of following use case

Tags: database, algorithm

All the records in a database is saved in (key, value) pair formats.Records can always be retrieved by specifying key value. Data structure needs to be developed to handle following scenarios

1. Access all the records in a linear fashion  (Array or linked list is best data structure for this scenario to access in O(N) time)
2. retrieve the record by providing the key (hash table can be implemented to index it in O(1) complexity)
3. Retrieve set of records for a value at a particular byte in the key . Ex: List of all records  for which 2nd number(10's place)  in the key should be 5 and  if the keys are 256, 1452, 362, 874, the records for keys , 256 and 1452 should be returned

Comment: your 3rd requirement is not clear. For which 2nd number should be 5?

Comment: I don't understand what is 3. supposed to mean. Can you provide an example? Also, why do you want this? Is this a homework?

Comment: This is for my pet project and am  way past to do homework

Comment: Walk through all the elements of what? A list? A tree? A disk file? There isn't enough information in this question to even attempt an answer.

Comment: I clarified the question now, should I need add any more information.All the data is present is in memory

Comment: given a number, how do you know if that s index or key ?

Comment: Are you just doing lookups on this structure, or insertions / deletions as well?

Comment: Please don't re-ask the same question.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you keys are at most d digits long (in decimal).

How about a normal hashtable and an additional 10*d two dimensional array (let's call it A) of sets. A[i][j] is the set of keys which have digit i in the jth position. The sets can support O(1) insert/delete if implemented themselves as hashtables.

Answer (score 2):

For 1 and 2, I think [Linked Hash Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) is a good choice.

For the point 3, an additional Hash map with (digit, position) tuple as key and list of pointers to the values.

Both data structures can be wrapped inside one, and both will point to the same data, of course.

Comment: I'm wondering how exactly that is going to help retrieve records keyed by a (digit, position) tuple, item 3 in the question. I thought the LHM was just a linked list with a hashmap--was I wrong?

Comment: Getting all keys and checking them? Pretty slow though. You can create an auxiliary data structure that contains that tuple, and use it as an additional key.

Answer (score 2):

Store the keys in a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).  For the numbers in your example (assuming 4 digit numbers) it looks like this:

```
*root*
 |
 0 -- 2 - 5 - 6
 | |
 | +- 3 - 6 - 2
 | |
 | +- 8 - 7 - 4
 |
 1 - 4 - 5 - 2
```

This data structure can be traversed in a way that returns (1) or (3).  It won't be quite as fast for (3) as would maintaining an index for each digit, so I guess it's a question of whether space or lookup time is your primary concern.  For (2), it is already O(log n), but if you need O(1), you could store the keys in both the trie and a hash table.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is embedding a pair of nodes in each record. One of the nodes would be a part of a tree sorted by the record index and the other, part of a tree sorted by the record key. You can then have quick access to the records by index or key using these trees. With this you can also quickly visit records in sequential index or key order. This covers the first and second requirement.

You can add another node for a tree of records whose values contain 5 in the tens position. That covers the third requirement.

Extra benefit: the same tree handling code will be used in all cases.

Comment: But his requirements say "Retrieve set of records for a value at a particular byte in the key." At minimum (using your idea), you'd need a tree for each possible digit position (i.e. a 1's tree, a 10's tree, a 100's tree, etc.)

Comment: @JimMischel: Previous editions of the question only considered 5s in tens.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary (hash map, etc.) would easily handle those requirements, although your third requirement would be an O(N) operation. You just iterate over the keys and select those that match your criteria. You don't say what your desired performance is for that case.

But O(N) might be plenty fast enough. How many items are in your data set, and how often will you be performing that third function?