# Propose Data structure for following case

Tags: c, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Data structure to handle the requirement of following use case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186650/data-structure-to-handle-the-requirement-of-following-use-case)

All the records in a database is saved in (key, value) pair formats.Records can always be retrieved by specifying key value. Data structure needs to be developed to handle following scenarios

1. Access all the records in a linear fashion (Array or linked list is best data structure for this scenario to access in O(N) time)
2. retrieve the record by providing the key (hash table can be implemented to index it in O(1) complexity)
3. Retrieve set of records for a value at a particular byte in the key . Ex: List of all records for which 2nd number(10's place) in the key should be 5 and if the keys are 256, 1452, 362, 874, the records for keys , 256 and 1452 should be returned